# R: How to count the total number of tokens in a corpus?

Tags: r, nlp, corpus, quanteda

I have created a Quanteda corpus called readtext_corpus with 190 types of text. I would like to count the total number of tokens or words in the corpus. I tried the function ntoken which gives a number of words per text not the total number of words for all 190 texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use the sum() function which is really simple. I left an example:

```
test <- c("testing string number 1","testing string number 2")

sum(quanteda::ntoken(test))
```

Result:

```
> quanteda::ntoken(test)
text1 text2 
    4     4 
> sum(quanteda::ntoken(test))
[1] 8
>
```

In case you are using pipes, which is pretty common with quanteda

```
> quanteda::ntoken(test) %>% sum()
[1] 8
```

Comment: Works for ntoken, doesn't work for ntype (when you want unique token count)... wish there was an easier way for this, they made this way too complicated - just have the ability to treat the corpus as a whole or as a a set of documents without having to recompile each case into separate objects.